# Trying to docker inspect State.Health gives `map has no entry for key "State"`

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use a Docker [HEALTHCHECK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) in a container. I'm setting that up in a version 3 docker-compose file, which also supports [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck):

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
  [...]
    healthcheck:
      test: test ! -e /unhealthy
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 1
```

In every place I can find, including on stackoverflow, the way to check the health of a container is to use `docker inspect` and look at `State.Health`, but no such entry exists:

```
$ docker inspect --format='{{json .State}}' api
Template parsing error: template: :1:7: executing "" at <.State>: map has no entry for key "State"
```

I googled around for quite a while but cannot see where this information moved to or any alternate ways to check health status.

Version info:

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac219
$ docker --version
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The service name `api` is a compose construct. Docker isn't able to map the name `api` to a container. I suspect you have another object named `api` that `docker inspect` it is looking up.

Compose containers are normally named `{{parent_directory}}-{{service}}-{{n}}`. To find the name use:

```
docker-compose ps
docker ps -a --filter name=SERVICE_NAME
```

Then you can use inspect on that name

```
docker inspect --format='{{json .State}}' CONTAINER_ID_OR_NAME
```

or specifically inspect containers to avoid non container objects:

```
docker container inspect --format='{{json .State}}' CONTAINER_ID_OR_NAME
```

All containers should have the `.State` object. Only containers with a healthcheck defined will have the `.State.Health` data.

Comment: I anonymized the container name, sorry if that was confusing. I think the name I was using was mapping to the correct container, since a quick glance at `docker inspect CONTAINER_NAME` looked okay, but I will try again with the specific container ID. But you seem to be saying that `State.Health` hasn't been moved and I should expect to see it there?

Comment: @djanderson Not exactly, the command/error posted was for just `.State`, which should always exist for a container so that's why I thought it was a non container object. `.State.Health` will only exist if the container has a healthcheck defined.

Comment: You were exactly right, I was inspecting an image and not a container, and I didn't have a good handle on which I was even supposed to be inspecting. I can now see the container's `State`, though it doesn't have a `Health` entry. But since you solved the actual error that was in the question, I'll accept this answer. Thank you! If you happen to come across any info about where `Health` went, please let me know.

Comment: I just saw you said `Health` is only there if the healthcheck is defined. I will try defining it in the Dockerfile instead of the docker-compose and see if it picks it up there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Matt's answer, which got me past the no `State` entry problem, I also needed remove all existing containers and rebuild them. I'm not sure why, but I can now see `.State.Health`.